# Android Lollipop Forgot Password

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, locked-out

I forgot my number password and I am unable to unlock my phone. I have tried looking things up online and the only solution I haven't tried is to perform a factory reset. I would prefer not to delete all of my data.

How do I reset/unlock my phone without knowing the password for the phone?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! As this is one of our most frequent questions, we've set up some first aid in our [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info). Please check that out, then come back here and either [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) when you were able to solve your issue, or [edit] it with what you've tried and where you're stuck otherwise. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The following steps may help you  to reset the moto-g without loosing your data.

step 1: Unlock Motorola Moto G Bootloader

step 2: Root your phone with M-TOOL

step 3: install  CWM(clockworkmod) recovery on your moto-g after rooting

step 4: choose RECOVERY from the Fastboot menu using your volume keys and
        enter recovery

step 5: then backup your moto-g using your volume keys and store it on sd 
        card

step 6: reset your phone using recovery ,and restore the backup

Comment: Wouldn't unlocking bootloader reset the device?